# how to avoid flickering when repopulating view?

Tags: android, flicker

My Android app shows a list of items which is refreshed every 30 second. After the container (linearlayout) is cleared, the new items are added to the view one by one in the do background work() method of  an asynctask. Asynctask is used because it involves network access.

When I run the app, I can see the list being redrawn ( flicker).

Is there a way to "delay/suspend" the redraw ?

Comment: have you tried adding your views in the UI thread?

Comment: Are you using Loaders?